# tricky setTimeout sequence

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Set of setTimeout calls with intervals 0,1,2,3.

```js
function f() {

    setTimeout(function a() {console.log(10);}, 3);

    setTimeout(function b() {console.log(20);}, 2);

    setTimeout(function c() {console.log(30);}, 1);

    setTimeout(function d() {console.log(40);}, 0);

}

f();
```

Output: (from chrome. Hope would be the same in other browsers)

30

40

20

10

Can someone explain clearly why is the ordering not 30, 40, 10, 20?
It is said browsers maintain a minimum 10ms or (spec says) 4ms interval. If so, validate the output with time metrics or whichever is convenient to explain this behavior. What minute detail am I missing to understand this awesome feature of the language?

Edited:

I know these functions are asynchronous. And I have read John Resig' blog couple of times. And I know a setTimeout' callback is not guaranteed to execute at the interval specified.

To be more precise, I expect an explanation that can explain the behavior in terms of execution queue, event loop, call stacks and timers.

Comment: that nothing is for certain in this life, much less  `setTimeout()`'s :) They are async and are not guaranteed to fire in any particular order

Comment: See: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Comment: Why should it be 30, 40, 10, 20?

Comment: Hint: try it with 0, 100, 200, 300

Comment: Why down vote on the question? Anyways, @cy3er I expected output to be  30, 40, 10, 20 with the same logic as how 30, 40 are logged in reverse order. The timer of the prior expires before the later is registered.

Comment: @Nicholas Kyriakides, if it is not guaranteed to fire in any particular order, any reason why they are fired always in same order?

Answer (score 1):

> In order to understand how the timers work internally there’s one
>   important concept that needs to be explored: timer delay is not
>   guaranteed. Since all JavaScript in a browser executes on a single
>   thread asynchronous events (such as mouse clicks and timers) are only
>   run when there’s been an opening in the execution.

Refer [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) and [this](http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval) for more details

Answer (score 1):

As @Jebin pointed out in a comment to the OP, you're running into a race condition here.

Here's the spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-settimeout

Step 13 is where we wait, and that waiting can happen while script is currently executing. See http://jsbin.com/faguli/edit?js,console - in this example "10" is logged first because the script takes a long time to get to the next `setTimeout`.

At a guess, in Chrome, the task for 3rd `setTimeout` is queued before JS manages the 4th call to `setTimeout`.

So, in this case both Chrome and Firefox are spec-compliant, despite giving different answers.

One way to make this deterministic would be to process `setTimeout` calls as part of a microtask, and start the timers from there, but `setTimeout` is an olllllld API, so changes here may break the web.